# Visual Studio settings: How to set vertical split view to default

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am working with C#(WPF) and when I open `XAML` file it splits to `Vertical` every time, I'm changing to `Horizontal`, but when I reopen again it still `Vertical`, is it possible to set default to `Horizontal` view.
Examples:
First is Vertical view
Second is Horizontal view

[image: Vertical view]

[image: Horizontal view]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is late answer, since this feature is available on `Visual Studio 2015`. For setting the `Xaml` code view to `Vertical` or `Horizontal` you can see steps below:
[image: Picture]

Comment: can you do this with VS2017 and database projects on the table/sql view?

Answer (score 2):

Custom layouts are a feature of the upcoming Visual Studio 2015. Users will be able to save a selection of custom layouts and save/load these.

Comment: Thanks! for letting know

Comment: With VS2017, I wanted to do change the default orientation of SQL / table designer. split. is that possible?