# vertical split of sql files in VS2015 and up

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, ide

This is perhaps an odd question, but there's a long .sql file I'd like to visualize in **vertical split** mode, like it is possible to do w[ith many source code files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645795/visual-studio-settings-how-to-set-vertical-split-view-to-default) in the Visual Studio IDE.
To my surprise, I see there's no way to do this with SQL files -see pic attached :-(

[image]
 While regular horizontal split is an option, it seems discouraging that SQL does not receive the same treatment in the IDE. Any solutions/suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After waiting a while from the community's input, I've realized that Notepad++'s  [*clone to other view* command](https://superuser.com/questions/332163/can-i-get-split-screen-in-notepad-like-emacs/332164)  has yet another adept ;-)